# Custom Android EditText not working

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-view, android-custom-view

I am trying to implement a custom `onDraw()` method in my `EditText`.
`onDraw` is getting called - I can see the log messages, but it is not drawing anything.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is an excerpt from my layout:

```
    <view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          class ="my.package.NotePadEditView"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:singleLine="false"
            >
        <requestFocus/>
    </view>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the class (just with some test code for now):

```
public class NotePadEditView extends EditText {
Paint paint = new Paint();
public NotePadEditView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
   super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
   paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
   paint.setColor(0xFF0000);
 }
 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   Log.d("NotePadEditView", "Calling onDraw()"); // These log messages are displaying
   canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 50, 50, paint); // just some random stuff so we know when we are done. (Note: these are not displaying - what's up with that???)
   canvas.drawText("Hello, World", 30, 30, paint);
   super.onDraw(canvas);
  }

// more constructors, etc
```

Comment: Try calling `super.onDraw(canvas);` first. Perhaps that is drawing on top of your `drawLine()` and `drawText()`.

Comment: I tried that - in fact I put the whole drawing thing in a method and called it both before and after the super.onDraw - crazy perplexing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, finally figured it out. Looks like you need to set the alpha byte on the color assignment:

```
paint.setColor(0x80FF0000);
```

not

```
paint.setColor(0xFF0000);
```

Apparently by excluding the alpha byte, you are implicitly passing in zero, which means the color is completely transparent. Java AWT doesn't work that way - who thought that was a good idea?!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try this thing to work Custom EditText in xml of android Layout.

Here is some change made by me in your Class.

```
public class NotePadEditView extends EditText{
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Log.d("NotePadEditView", "Calling onDraw()"); // These log messages are displaying
       canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 50, 50, paint); // just some random stuff so we know when we are done. (Note: these are not displaying - what's up with that???)
       canvas.drawText("Hello, World", 30, 30, paint);
       super.onDraw(canvas);

}
Paint paint;

public NotePadEditView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    //this Contructure required when you are using this view in xml 
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
}

public NotePadEditView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setColor(0xFF0000);

   }

}
```

Use in your xml like this ,

```
   <my.package.NotePadEditView 
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:singleLine="false" />
```

hope this will make your work.

Comment: I don't see much difference - I am already setting up the paint in all constructors, and your xml I believe is equivalent to mine.

Comment: But i get Error while use your code in which you don't have `NotePadEditView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` this parametrized constructor.if we don't add this in class it will create problem in use in xml layout.and i can see blue line draw over Edittext.

Comment: Yes, I have that constructor, I just did not show it in the code - you see on the bottom there is a comment that says "more constructors". Sorry for the confusion. Anyway, it is still not working